# Liquibase changeset deploy with php

Tags: php, database, postgresql, deployment, liquibase

Is there an existing solution to deploy liquibase changesets with php?

I mean sadly my production server has only ftp and php capabilities, so I cannot install anything with ssh, but I intend to version my database schema changes along with my code...

Comment: Is there a jvm on your prod server? If you plan on calling liquibase from php on that prod server you need to have a jvm installed (since liquibase is written in java). An alternative might be to not call liquibase from php. Just run liquibase from any client that has a jvm and access to the database.

Comment: As I said, the production server has no such capabilities. I thought I just upload the changesets with ftp and run a php script which applies the changes on the databases. I intend to use the liqui* softwares on the dev machines only...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Liquibase requires a Java JVM to run, there is not a PHP port. However, liquibase does support updateSQL mode which you can run against your production database (or a backup/copy) to generate a sql script containing the changes to deploy. You can then run that script against the database however you like.